# Variant of 2-SUM Problem using Hashtable with multi-threading

Tags: python, multithreading, time-limit-exceeded, hash-map

I am doing a Coursera assignment on Hashtable and my solution is taking too long to run. Here is the problem as described in the [assignment](https://www.coursera.org/learn/algorithms-graphs-data-structures):

> The goal of this problem is to implement a variant of the 2-SUM algorithm covered in this week's lectures.
>
> The file contains 1 million integers, both positive and negative (there might be some repetitions!).This is your array of integers, with the ith row of the file specifying the ith entry of the array.
>
> Your task is to compute the number of target values t in the interval [-10000,10000] (inclusive) such that there are distinct numbers x,y in the input file that satisfy x+y=t

Here is my entire Python code:

```
from collections import defaultdict
import threading

def hash_fn(n):
    M=1999993
    return n%M

def two_sum_present(target):
    global ans
    bool=True
    for x in nums:
        y = target-x
        if y in my_hash_table[hash_fn(y)] and y!=x:
            bool=False
            ans+=1
            return 1
    if bool == True:
        return 0
f = open('_6ec67df2804ff4b58ab21c12edcb21f8_algo1-programming_prob-2sum.txt')
nums=[]
my_hash_table = defaultdict(list)    
for line in f.readlines():
    num = int(line.split('\n')[0])
    nums.append(num)
    my_hash_table[hash_fn(num)].append(num)

ans=0
for nr in range(-10000, 10001):
    thr = threading.Thread(target = two_sum_present, args=(nr,))
    thr.start()

print(ans)
```

Notes:

1. I found a page for the same problem [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/135392/2-sum-problem-on-a-range-in-python), but this solution uses neither hashing nor binary search, so it should take longer than my solution. This solution is essentially this:

   ```
    ans = sum(any(n-x in nums and 2*x != n for x in nums) for n in range(-10000, 10001))
   ```
2. The text file can be found [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/piyush-kgp/Algorithms-Specialization-Stanford/master/Graph%20Search%2C%20Shortest%20Paths%2C%20and%20Data%20Structures/2-SUM%20algorithm%20using%20Hash%20Table/_6ec67df2804ff4b58ab21c12edcb21f8_algo1-programming_prob-2sum.txt). if someone is interested. But think of it as a  big text file with 1M lines having 1 integer(+ve or -ve) on each line.
3. 'distinct' as mentioned here only means that x+x=t is not a valid 2-sum pair; but two (x, y) pairs where x and y are not same constitute a valid pair

Comment: Please fix the indentation in your code. The `hash_fn` is misaligned for eg.

Comment: Sorry for bad indentation there. Fixed it.

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! I hope you get some great answers.

Comment: Your hash table will have collisions (you are not checking for equality before overwriting an existing entry) and your hash function is not really doing much for you.  Try this trick, change your hash function to return the number you pass in to it, is it faster?  I suspect it will be.

Comment: Oops, noticed you do check for equality.  In any case, I think your algorithm will be faster if you don't use hashing.

Clue: `len(set(hash_fn(n) for n in range(-10000,10001))) == 20001`

Comment: Did you try __not__ using multi threading first? I suspect that, in such CPU bound tasks, Python thread model and the GIL is slowing the whole thing down.

Comment: Yes, I tried without multi-threading, still takes too long. Do you think I should use a different hashing function; keeping in mind that nums may contain large numbers (10 digits) and there are 1M of them. The reason for using1999993 was that it is prime and close to 2M; a multiple of 1M (the number of numbers).  I tried without hashing but still too slow (which it should be).  How do I create a more efficiently searchable hash table?

Comment: It should be noted that the `threading` package from python does not use multiple cores. It only simulates threading for asynchronous tasks. Thus, it is excellent for web-scrapers and other tasks that involve a lot of waiting for data. However, this is not such a case, and the `threading` package will only make the script run slower. Also, before creating a threaded solution, make sure that the test bench running the script does indeed support multicore computing, or you're wasting your time. If it does, check out the `multiprocessing` package.

Comment: what is "too long"?

Comment: I let the code run in the background for around half an hour; then I stopped it because it clearly isn't meant to run that long. But using an answer here; I was able to write a more efficient solution (an improvement over the answer provided) which ran in 3 seconds. [See my answer below and the one it is inspired from]

Comment: @PiyushSingh I removed the link that you changed in your last edit because strange things happened when I clicked the link. Maybe the site is infected.

Comment: Hi, I re-added the link of the text file. Also, it is not given in the question that the numbers are between -10^11 to 10^11 or that they are uniformly distributed in an interval or that there is no integer in [-10000, 10000]. Moreover, the problem can be solved without any of these assumptions. In fact, your last assumption does away with the distinct pair thing mentioned in the question. [Please read note 3]. If you are trying to solve the problem yourself,  try doing so without making assumptions of yourself. If you want the solution, see my answer. Ran in 3s and was accepted by Coursera.

Comment: These aren't "assumption" I made but these are facts about the file your post references to.  The numbers are between -10^11 to 10^11  and there is no integer in [-10000, 10000] and the numbers seem to be uniformly distributed.

Answer (score 2):

## functions

split the work you want to do in logical functions. I try to limit the work that is done in the general script (and thus the global namespace) as much as possible. Lookups of local variable are supposed to be faster, but it make the code easier to read and test as well, so win-win.

## hashing

Why device your own hashing? just dumping all the numbers in a set will eliminate all the duplicates, and 1M integers is a limited amount of memory. Certainly a lot less that the `defaultdict` you use

## global variable ans

Instead of passing the global variable `ans`, the easiest way would be to use the fact that in a numeric context (like `sum`), `True` equals 1 and `False` equals 0, so you can just return True or False in `two_sum_present`

## my take on this:

### read the file

Using the fact that a file is an iterator, I would do something like this

```
def read_file(filename):
    with open(filename, 'r') as file:
        return set(map(int, file))
```

### find the target

About the same as your `two_sum_present` with my remarks incorporated

```
def find_target(numbers, target):
    for i in numbers:
        if target - i in numbers and 2 * i != target:
            return True
    return False
```

### iterate over the interval

```
def find_sums(numbers, start=-10000, end=10000):
    for target in range(start, end + 1):
#         print(target)
        yield find_target(numbers, target)
```

### putting it together

```
def main(filename, start=-10000, end=10000):
    numbers = read_file(filename)
#     print(f'numbers found: {len(numbers)}')
    return sum(find_sums(numbers, start, end))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    filename = 'data/_6ec67df2804ff4b58ab21c12edcb21f8_algo1-programming_prob-2sum.txt'
    print(main(filename, -100, 100))
```

All in all, it took 43 seconds to scan those 201 numbers on my system, to find 5 matches. Reading the file took about .6s of that time

This solution is essentially the same as `sum(any(n-x in numbers and 2*x != n for x in numbers) for n in range(-100, 101))`, but that one took 59s

## Multithreading

If you want to, you can divide out all the call to `find_target` to different workers/cores/... In this case, a `frozenset` instead of a `set` might be more appropriate since it's immutable, and will give less problems with concurrency

## distinct

As noted by Gareth Rees, the original question is ambiguous on what is mean with `distinct numbers x,y`. To cover the second interpretation, You can change the `set` to a `collections.Counter`, and change the test criterium slightly

```
from collections import Counter

def read_file_distinct(filename):
    with open(filename, 'r') as file:
        return Counter(map(int, file))

def find_sums_distinct(numbers, start=-10000, end=10000):
    for target in range(start, end + 1):
#         print(target)
        yield find_target_distinct(numbers, target)

def find_target_distinct(numbers, target):
    for i in numbers:
        if target - i in numbers and (2 * i != target or numbers[i] > 1):
            return True
    return False

def main_distinct(filename, start=-10000, end=10000):
    numbers = read_file_distinct(filename)
#     print(f'numbers found: {len(numbers)}')
    return sum(find_sums_distinct(numbers, start, end))
```

This has an effect on speed, though

> ```
> %timeit main(filename, -10, 10)
> ```

```
4.51 s ± 32.5 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

> ```
> %timeit main_distinct(filename, -10, 10)
> ```

```
6.42 s ± 48.4 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

## distinct 2

A slightly different, faster approach can be used to tackle the 2nd interpretation

```
def find_sums_distinct2(numbers, repetitions,start=-10000, end=10000):
    for target in range(start, end + 1):
#         print(target)
        yield find_target_distinct2(numbers, repetitions, target)

def find_target_distinct2(numbers, repetitions, target):
    for i in numbers:
        if target - i in numbers and (2 * i != target or i in repetitions):
            return True
    return False

def main_distinct2(filename, start=-10000, end=10000):
    numbers = read_file_distinct(filename)
    repetitions = {k for k, v in numbers.items() if ((v > 1) and (start < k < end))}
#     print(repetitions)
    numbers = set(numbers)
#     print(f'{len(numbers)} numbers found, {len(repetitions)} repetitions')
    return sum(find_sums_distinct2(numbers, repetitions, start, end))
```

> ```
> %timeit main_distinct2(filename, -10, 10)
> ```

```
4.92 s ± 160 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to handle the possibility of repetitions in the input.

Comment: does it need to? The question mentions `such that there are distinct numbers x,y in the input file that satisfy x+y=t`. If instead by distinct they also mean 2 repetitions of the same number, then a `Counter` might be more appropriate, with a slightly revised test like `if target - i in numbers and (2 * i != target or numbers[i] > 1)`

Comment: The question is not exactly clear on this point. From a pragmatic point of view, why note "there might be some repetitions" unless this is relevant somehow? But on the other hand, you're right that "distinct" suggests \$x \ne y\$.

Comment: the question is unclear on this point indeed, and I selected one interpretation. I will try to adapt the answer to include both interpretations

Comment: @MaartenFabré I have added the meaning of 'distinct' in the question. Also in find_target function you should search only in the range [-10000-target, 10000-target], because, that's where any relevant complementary number for that number might lie; if any. Also you don't need to search for 10001 because we are not interested if any number pair add up to 10001. For completion, I am adding my own answer which ran in 2 seconds on my PC.

Answer (score 1):

```
import bisect
num_set = set()
with open('_6ec67df2804ff4b58ab21c12edcb21f8_algo1-programming_prob-2sum.txt') as file:
    for num in file.read().splitlines():
        num = int(num)
        num_set.add(num)

num_list = sorted(num_set)
targets = set()
for num in num_list:
    low = bisect.bisect_left(num_list, -10000-num)
    high = bisect.bisect_right(num_list, 10000-num)
    for num_2 in num_list[low:high]:
        if num_2 != num:
            targets.add(num+num_2)

print(len(targets))
```

Using Maarten's code, I wrote this; but I limited my search range for each number to [-10000-number, 10000-number] because that's where any relevant number for that number will lie; if any. This helped greatly with the running time.